# How to run sparql query on the results of another sparql query?(subquery not allowed)

Tags: java, sparql, jena, ontology

I Have the following query which works fine. The problem is the program I am working with does not support subqueries. Is there a way to run the inner select query first, get the results and then and run the outer select query on the result set?

```
String query = "select ?property (str(?value) as ?valueLiteral) (str(count(distinct ?ind)) as ?count)
                    where { ?ind rdf:type ?x. ?ind  ?property ?value.
                                ?property a owl:DatatypeProperty .
                           {
                               select distinct ?x ?class
                                  where { ?x rdf:type owl:Class }
                           }
                     } 
                    group by ?property ?value
                    order by ?property";
```

I appreciate your help very much

Comment: which program does not allow subqueries? And why would you need a subquery here? what is the purpose of this subquery at all? The subquery itself is also wrong, `?class` is not bound in the subquery.

Comment: By the way, you added the tag `jena`, this does indeed support full SPARQL 1.1 and therefore subquery.

Comment: There's nothing in the standard to make this a single operation, but you could CONSTRUCT { ... } WHERE { ... }, save that graph, and then query over that graph.  Some libraries may have something like that available as an extension (I remember RobV saying that a .NET library had it, I think.)

Comment: @UninformedUser I am working on a project in which we use sparql queries. I was told that their data does not support the subqueries so I could not have nested select queries. I tested the entire query on protege and it worked. Sorry I am new to ontology, what to do you mean by not bound..?

Comment: you do `select distinct ?x ?class
                                  where { ?x rdf:type owl:Class }` in the subquery, so what do you think will be bound to the variable `?class`?

Comment: and then, what is your query supposed to do in the end? That would help in understanding what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: So first I try to get all the distinct classes, and then from those get the properties and their value, per each distinct individual.

Comment: The other thing that I just found out is they dont support owl classes. So how can I get all the distinct classes? select distinct ?class where {?class ... }?

Comment: I'm not sure what is being asked for - a form with no sub-query or a way to execute so the inner select executes first. In fact, I don't see why there is an inner select at all - `?x rdf:type owl:Class` does not add anything because ?x is used in `?ind rdf:type ?x` so it is a class if it matches. `?class` is never used.

Comment: Jena has subquery. If it is first in the pattern, it will be executed earlier and once. The results are the same; only the optimization is affected.

Comment: @DjSh there is no need to get all distinct classes via a subquery. I mean, the only thing the class information does for you is to just consider only individuals that belong to a class. That's all. And this can just be achieved by using the triple pattern `?ind rdf:type ?x` . That's all.

Comment: And using `owl:DatatypeProperty` and `owl:Class` to find those schema entities only works if this information is a) explicitly in your data or b) you have some kind of OWL reasoning (`OntModel` in case of Apache Jena possibly) enabled. It's mostly a matter of the serialization of the OWL ontology if those triples are in the data, APIs like OWL API or tools based on OWL API (e.g. Protege) can also infer those types by parsing other axioms